# Why does the Soda Popper take 2 bullets when I have 1 loaded?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-scout

I was playing with the Soda Popper and noticed something interesting - if I reloaded when I had 1 bullet, I lost 2 from my off-hand ammo anyways.

I made sure mods were disabled on the server I was playing on (they were), but I still lost 2 ammo regardless.

Why does this happen? Is it just how the game works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is standard behavior for the [Soda Popper](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1dr_7bZrQY) and the [Force of Nature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPFTBw7owko).  The reload animation always shows two shells being ejected, so the reload takes two.  As for why this happens, I'm not certain if the developers have commented.